# Sequelize - Cannot save associations in 1:N relationship

Tags: postgresql, orm, sequelize.js, rdbms

### What you are doing?

trying to add associations and save them to database

```
js

var Device = models.Device;
var Log = models.Log;;

var logs = [
    {
        "message_level" : 1,
        "message" : "test log 1"
    },
    {
        "message_level" : 1,
        "message" : "test log 2"
    },
    {
        "message_level" : 1,
        "message" : "test log 3"
    }
];

var devID = 'X3dE4DEW';

describe('Logs', function() {
    it('should create log', function(done) {
        Device.create({
            "originalID" : devID
        }).then(
            function() {
                return Device.findOne({"where": {originalID: devID}, 
                                       include: [ { model: Log, as : "Logs" } ] }).then(
                    function(device) {
                        if (device) {
                            logs = logs.map(
                                function(log) {
                                    return Log.build(log);
                                }
                            );
                            console.log(logs) // is NOT Empty -> OK
                            return device.addLogs(logs).then(
                                function(device) {
                                    return device.getLogs().then(
                                        function(logs) {
                                            console.log(logs); // EMPTY [] -> NOT OK
                                            logs.length.should.equal(3);
                                            done();
                                        }
                                    );
                                }
                            );
                        }

                        return Promise.reject('Not valid Device ID');
                    }
                ).catch(function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                    done();
                });
            }
        );
    });
});
```

here is how are they defined

```
// models
// Device
  Device = pg.define('device', {
    originalID: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING(16) // Up to 16
    }
  });

// LogRecord
  Log = pg.define('log', {
    message_level: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    message: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING(100) // Up to 100
    }
  });
  Device.hasMany(Log, { as : "Logs" });
  Log.belongsTo(Device);
```

### What do you expect to happen?

`addLogs` should save associations items to the database

### What is actually happening?

Items are not saved, `device.getLogs()` is returning an empty array `[]`

```
{ AssertionError: expected 0 to equal 3 }
```

**Dialect:** PG
**Database version:** 9.6.1
**Sequelize version:** ~3.30.x

Comment: but where is your `addLogs` method defined? :-? shouldn't it be on the `device` model?

Comment: @OvidiuDolha sequelize generate virtual functions `add<Association(s)>` among with `set, get and remove`

Comment: ah, that cheeky b@#$!rd

Answer (score 0):

There's several solutions to associate rows

- if you're using `add<Association(s)>` function, be sure that associated objects are already stored in database.
- or you can use `create<Association>` to create model and associate.

  ```
  var device;
  Device.create({
      "originalID" : devID
  }).then(function(createdDevice) {
      device = createdDevice;
      return Promise.all(logs.map(log=>{return device.createLog(log);}));
  }).then(function(result) {
      return device.getLogs();
  }).then(function(logs) {
      console.log(logs);
      logs.length.should.equal(3);
      done();
  }).catch(function(error){
      console.log(error);
      done();
  });
  ```

  Use promises style like above, it's more understandable, not "go deep into promises".